# Prove P from B ∨ P when we have proven ¬B

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I have the following proof so far:

[image: proof]

In step 9 I'm not sure how to prove P from the steps I have before. I thought that I could use ∨ Elim but I don't think I can now.

Comment: $(B\lor P)\equiv (\lnot(\lnot B\land\lnot P))\equiv(\lnot B\implies P)$

Comment: @trying The first $\equiv$ isn't constructively valid from left to right.

Comment: @DanielV He is using DeMorgan's Law and the definition of implication. How is that invalid?

Comment: @DanChristensen Many classical laws aren't constructive.  For DeMorgan's, $\lnot (\lnot A \lor \lnot B) \to (A \lor B)$, just take $B = \lnot A$ and you get $\lnot \lnot A \to A$, double negation elimination which is not taken for granted.

Comment: @DanielV So, it is valid in what you call "classical" logic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use $\bot \ Elim$. Now, to continue from what you have, you can do:

[image]

But note that you never used the subproof on lines 5-7, so this can be simplified to:

[image]

Although conceptually, it may be helpful to keep the original subproof, and (since it shows that $B$ leads to a contradiction $\bot$) derive $\neg B$, and to then combine $\neg B$ with $B \lor P$ (the latter is a **super** common patterns, so remember that one!!):

[image]

Finally, you can set this up as a proof by cases within a conditional proof, i.e. derive your goal $P \land D$ from each of the cases $B$ and $P$:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've actually seen some texts define Or-Elimination as $$\frac{\lnot B,~ B \lor P}{P}$$ which is actually constructively valid.  Anyway, the way to get there from regular Or-Elimination (proof by cases) is just to show that in both cases of $B$ and case $P$ that $P$ follows:

$$\begin{array} {rll}
(1) & \lnot B & \text{Given} \\ \\
%
(2) & \quad B & \text{assumption, Case 1} \\
%
(3) & \quad \bot & \text{Contradiction} \\
%
(4) & \quad P & \text{Explosion} \\ \\
%
(5) & \quad P & \text{assumption, Case 2} \\ \\
%
(6) & B \lor P & \text{Given} \\
%
(7) &  P & \text{Proof by cases (Or Elim) of 6, 2 through 4, 5 through 5} \\
%
\end{array}$$